# ROS Answers SE migration: pycharm setup

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use pycharm as my ide and it doesn't seem to recognize any of the ros libraries(rospy, etc.) even though they are properly installed. If it helps I am using python 3.4.0 and pycharm 4.0.4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204326/pycharm-setup/) by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably similar to running an [IDE](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) and getting it to code-complete ROS code.

Have you tried starting pycharm from a terminal in which you have sourced your `setup.bash`?

Otherwise make sure to check your `PYTHONPATH`, it should contain (at least) `/opt/ros/$ros_release/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-05**:
Thanks, adding the `PYTHONPATH` to the Pycharm Environment Variables fixed the problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-05**:
It probably works, but I'd go for the "sourced environment" option. If anything ever changes in ROS wrt Python setup/paths, you don't have to do anything. Setting the `PYTHONPATH` (or adding it to pycharm's setup) would mean you'd have to track any changes in ROS manually.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't forget to have a look at:

http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

There is not only a solution for your problem. But also there is a solution for using PyCharm as debugger.

As a better choice for solving your problem, add  `bash -i -c`  to your PyCharm's desktop file
There is something like:

`Exec="/opt/pycharm-community-4.0.4/bin/pycharm.sh" %f`

change it to:

`Exec=bash -i -c "/opt/pycharm-community-4.0.4/bin/pycharm.sh" %f`

You can find the desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` with filename `pycharm.desktop` or might have another name but includes pycharm and has a .desktop extension.

---

Originally posted by [tekin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26271/tekin/) with karma: 86 on 2017-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on 2018-11-25**:
On ubuntu 16.04, installed the latest PyCharm. There is no pycharm desktop file. But:

./snap/pycharm-community/99/meta/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
./snap/pycharm-community/99/snap/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
./var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop

**Comment by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on 2018-11-25**:
the files at snap are not editable. because of some sort of read-only file system that snap uses. The file under /var/lib/snapd is editable and it has this line:

Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop /snap

**Comment by [xieshuaix](https://answers.ros.org/users/38970/xieshuaix/) on 2018-12-12**:
Same here, I have been wondering how to source before launching Pycharm installed via snap.

**Comment by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on 2019-02-13**:
Surprisingly, PyCharm run from the terminal works fine, while patching .desktop with -i -c options does not enable PyCharm to load environment variables including PYTHONPATH.

**Comment by [Tobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/88707/tobi/) on 2021-11-02**:
As I struggled too, here the modified Exec for the file '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop' to solve the sourcing:
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop bash -i -c /snap/bin/pycharm-community %f